# What's the verb that describes a color going closer to gray?

Tags: word-request, verbs

For example, blue becomes kinda like purple. White kinda like gray. Green kinda like brown.

Is there a word (a verb) to describe this change? (Which isn't *grayed*?)

Comment: Are you asking about colours that "fade" or lose their brightness?

Comment: I wish to state here for the record that purple is not more grey than blue.

Comment: The most intense hue of a pigment is fully *saturated*; to grey it back is to *desaturate* it.

Comment: I was going to say, "desaturate". You can use the "saturation" sliders in programs like Photoshop to take an image fully to grayscale.

Comment: Each color nuance is defined by a [pantone color number](https://www.pantone.com/pantone-numbering-explained). This is very important in printing industry.

Comment: Late here - As to the Pantone system: is there a term for a progression through a path of Pantone values or do you just list the specific color values you are addressing/suggesting/determining for that sequence/succession/degradation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of technical terms used to describe color.

> **Hue** defines pure color in terms of "green", "red" or "magenta". Hue also defines mixtures of two pure colors
>
> A **tint** is a mixing result of an original color to which has been added white.
>
> A **shade** is a mixing result of an original color to which has been added black.
>
> **Tone** is the result of mixing a pure color with any grayscale color (sometimes including white and black)
>
> **Lightness** defines a range from dark (0%) to fully illuminated (100%). Any original hue has the average lightness level of 50%.
>
> **Saturation** defines a range from pure color (100%) to gray (0%) at a constant lightness level. A pure color is fully saturated.

And others.  [More information on this page](http://www.workwithcolor.com/color-properties-definitions-0101.htm)

It's not clear which of these terms your question refers to, but my guess is that you are talking about *saturation*.  The term for removing saturation from a hue is **desaturation**.  Example:

Fully saturated blue:

[image]

50% *desaturated* blue:

[image]

100% *desaturated* blue:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A couple terms come to mind but with different meanings:

**Wash out** in the context of color means to dilute or desaturate, which may have a "greying" effect.

**Muddy** in the context of color means to darken or mix, usually associated with browns but could also be considered "greying" for some colors.